# python sounddevice: asynchronous playback with complicated callback

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, pyaudio, python-sounddevice

I'm using the python sounddevice module to provide "audio feedback" for a digital sensor. The idea is I have a sensor with one-dimensional time-series data being read in at 40 Hz. I have a target value  that I want the sensor to read. If the sensor is close to that target then a pure sine wave is played, if it's not then the pure tone is superposed with white noise of an amplitude proportional to the error. The audio and sensor reading is done asynchronously. I based the solution off the example of playing a [sine wave](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.6/examples.html#play-a-sine-signal) and the [asynchronous examples](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.6/examples.html#using-a-stream-in-an-asyncio-coroutine) from the documentation. I sort of just merged the two solutions together without understanding exactly what's going on. What I've got actually works, but I don't fully understand the API and I'm certain I'm doing some very ugly stuff.

I have a minimal working example below, where I mimic data being read in at 40 Hz to the Sensor class. I'd just like some advice on how to improve the code, especially since I am planning to make the callback function more complicated, so that it can respond to different events in the sensor input.

```py
import asyncio
import sounddevice as sd
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np

#white noise
def white(N):
    return np.random.randn(N)

start_idx = 0
async def play_audio(sensor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    samplerate = sd.query_devices(1, 'output')['default_samplerate']
    freq = 500.
    def callback(outdata, frames, time, status):
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        global start_idx
        y = sensor.data[-1]
        t = (start_idx + np.arange(frames)) / samplerate
        t = t.reshape(-1, 1)
        sine_wave = 0.5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t)
        scale_factor = abs(sensor.target - y) / sensor.target

        # if latest data is within threshold of target play pure tone
        if y > sensor.target - sensor.threshold and y < sensor.target + sensor.threshold:
            outdata[:] = sine_wave
        # else play noisy pure tone with amplitude 
        # proportional to error 
        else: 
            noisy_wave = scale_factor * white(len(t)).reshape(-1,1)
            noisy_wave += sine_wave
            outdata[:] = noisy_wave[:frames]
        start_idx += frames

    stream = sd.OutputStream(device=1, channels=1, callback=callback,
                         samplerate=samplerate)
    with stream:
        await event.wait()

class Sensor(): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = timer()
        self.target = 5.
        self.threshold = 0.2
        self.sample_frequency = 40.
        self.input_period = 10
        self.data = [0]

    async def read(self):
        while True:
            time = timer()-self.start_time
            self.data.append(self.input(time))
            await asyncio.sleep(1./self.sample_frequency)

    # mimics the input that the sensor would read with 
    # shifted sine wave of period `self.input_period`
    def input(self, time):
        arg = 2 * np.pi * time / self.input_period
        return self.target + np.sin(arg)

sensor = Sensor()

# read sensor data and play audio feedback
async def main():
        try:
            async with asyncio.timeout(10):
                await asyncio.gather(sensor.read(), play_audio(sensor))
        except TimeoutError:
            print("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: in general asyncio won't be the better approach for things that like real-time measurements, like audio - it is not guarranteed to return in times like "1/500"  (your sleep of "1/sample_frequency" ) - and more time than that can pass. The timings provided by asyncio should be ok for playing lenghts - but not for audio frequency. This does not mean it won't work, though. You might get better results with multi-threading and plain `time.sleep`  there.

Comment: playing lengths? can you clarify what you mean there? I was using asyncio because I also have an interactive plot that displays sensor data in real time and that is built using asyncio. I don't know how feasible it would be to use multi-threading and asyncio?

Comment: for "playing lengths" I mean the duration of a sound. (len(frames) / sample_rate)

Comment: if asyncio is working fine for you, you can use it. It is just that its time resolution will start failing when you request pauses with a 1/500 sec magnitude - so, if that is not critical (imagine you might get a pause 10 or 20% greater than that, in  a non-deterministic way), you can use asyncio. 
That said, the example above is missing a setting of the `event` - can you fix that?

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestions. I thought `asyncio.run()` implicitly manages the event loop though

Comment: yes, there is an event loop - and it  "self manages",  `asyncio.run` just starts it.  What happens is that asynchronous activities, by their very nature, cannot have a high precision in timing events.